# How to create POST service URL and save data to DB using Laravel 5?

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-5

i want to get some data from a mobile app using POST and save it on my laravel 5 application database.

mycontroller

```
public function postBookingDetails(Request $request)
{
    $FodMaps = $request->only('name','fructose');
    return $FodMaps;
}
```

---

```
Route::post('booking', 'FodMapController@postBookingDetails');
```

table Structre:

- id (autoincrement)
- name varchar
- fructose varchar

Model

```
protected $table = 'food_directory';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'lactose', 'fructose','polyols','fructan'];
```

Comment: Please show your table structure and Model File

Comment: What do you mean with fix this? You didn't do anything until now. What doesn't work?

Comment: @Ymartin  pls check updated question

Comment: What is the name of your model? is it FoodDirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function postBookingDetails(Request $request)
{
    $FodMaps = $request->only('name','fructose');
    $FoodDirectory = new FoodDirectory;
    $FoodDirectory->name = $request->input('name');
    $FoodDirectory->fructose = $request->input('fructose');
    $FoodDirectory->save(); 

    return $FoodDirectory;
}
```

also add to your model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

And ofcourse dont forget to add to the top of your controller:

```
use App\FoodDirectory;
```

Comment: thanks , but im getting TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46: error on POST method . any solution for this. is it ok to disable CsrfToken ? else how can i proceed with this,

Comment: u should add somthing like this in your form (in view): `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">` read this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: sorry about view. you have moblie-app

Comment: you should remove `'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'` from your app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: yes im receiving data from mobile app which developed using ionic javascript framework. if so do i have to handle it from that side ?